# MS Access - #Name? Error on DLookup (Textbox on Form, Lookup From Query)

Tags: ms-access

I'm having a bit of an issue with an MS Access database that I'm working on.  I'll try to give as much detail as I can.  All of my SQL code is what MS Access has generated for me.

First of all, I have a query that tells me how many hours a person is putting into project work -

```
SELECT Functions.f_Person, Sum(Functions.f_Hrs) AS SumOff_Hrs
FROM Functions
GROUP BY Functions.f_Person;
```

f_Person is Text in a combo box (linked to e_person in 'Employees' table which is a primary key), f_Hrs & Sumoff_Hrs are numbers.  I realise that I am not using best practice for that primary key.  This database will be rebuilt after proof of concept.

From this query I have created a second query that takes all of a person's contracted time and subtracts the previous total -

```
SELECT q_TotalHrs.f_Person, Employees.e_Hrs, q_TotalHrs.SumOff_Hrs, [Employees]![e_Hrs]-[q_TotalHrs]![SumOff_Hrs] AS HrsAvailable
FROM Employees, q_TotalHrs
GROUP BY q_TotalHrs.f_Person, Employees.e_Hrs, q_TotalHrs.SumOff_Hrs, [Employees]![e_Hrs]-[q_TotalHrs]![SumOff_Hrs];
```

This gives me something along these lines -

```
Person    Contract Hrs    Sumoff_Hrs    HrsAvailable
----------------------------------------------------
Ali       37              12            25
Al        37              1             36
Andy      37              1             36
Dave      37              13            24 
Gaz       37              1             36
John      37              1             36
Paul      37              6             31
George    37              2             35
Ringo     37              1             36
```

I also have a form (frm_Projects) which is used for creating new projects which has a subform (frm_Functions) for adding people to these projects.  This subform populates the 'Functions' table referenced in the first query.

So the user would add a function (f_Function) and then the number of hours required (f_Hrs) and selects a name from a combo box (f_Person).  The subform view is set to 'Continuous Forms'.

Now my problem:

I have created a text box at the end of the input line on the subform which should show the hours available for the selected person.  In the text box properties I have added this code into the Control Source -

```
=DLookUp("[HrsAvailable]","[q_HrsAvailable]","[f_Person] =" & [Forms]![frm_Functions]![f_Person])
```

This gives me the *#Name?* error on the form view.

I realise that this is a common problem, but can't seem to solve it on my own database using solutions that I've found.  Could somebody help me to fix this?

----------- Edit ----------------

New formula as provided by @Andre

```
=DLookUp("[HrsAvailable]","[q_HrsAvailable]","[f_Person] =" & [Forms]![frm_Projects]![frm_Functions].[Form]![f_Person])
```

Comment: http://access.mvps.org/access/forms/frm0031.htm -- you need Forms!Mainform!Subform1.Form!ControlName

Comment: Hi @Andre thanks for that.  Looks like a good resource.  I'm still struggling with the layout of the formula though.  I've tried a bunch of combinations.  Should it look like - ...& [Forms]![frm_Projects]![Subform1].[frm_Functions]![cbx_Person])?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say you need

```
Forms!frm_Projects!frm_Functions.Form!f_Person
```

assuming that the subform control (!) on `frm_Projects` has the same name as its source form, i.e. `frm_Functions`. That's normally the case, but not mandatory.

**Edit**

If you still have the combobox name change, it's

```
Forms!frm_Projects!frm_Functions.Form!cbx_Person
```

and since I now realize that `f_person` is a string, you need single quotes around the parameter:

```
=DLookUp("[HrsAvailable]", "[q_HrsAvailable]", 
         "[f_Person] = '" & [Forms]![frm_Projects]![frm_Functions].[Form]![f_Person] & "'")
```

Comment: Hi again.  I've edited the formula as above edit in my question.  This now gives me '#Error', which is possibly an improvement.  I don't know what I'm missing

Comment: *Dear diary! Today I progressed from #Name? to #Error!* :) -- see edit.

Comment: Absolutely!  And yes, the single quotes worked a treat.  That's exactly what I needed.  It bothers me that I can still miss things that look like they should be simple.  Just started with Access though.  I'll learn, and its a good way to settle myself into SQL.  Thanks @Andre

Comment: Also, its taken me a little while to understand exactly why the single quote was required, but I get it now.  Quite simple really :p

Comment: But watch out for people who have a `'` in their name (`O'Brian`). As you wrote above, names aren't the perfect choice for primary keys, an autonumber would be better. If you are stuck with it, you can use `Replace(...![f_Person], "'", "''")` to escape them.